# Custom Liferay DDMFormFieldType won't appear in Rules Dataprovider Inputs

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I wrote a custom Liferay 7.3 `DDMFormFieldType` which is mostly a text input field. I used the 7.3 blade example component and slightly modified the generated Soy template.
Basically, everything works fine. I can use my field inside a Liferay Forms. But I can't use this field inside a FormRule as Input parameter for dataproviders.
I thinks this is maybe due to a type mismatch (dataprovider input type is 'text'), but I don't know how to configure this for my fieldtype. What do I need to code in my custom fieldtype, so that it can be used for dataprovider inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue too. I have found that liferay is looking for specific hard-coded field types such as select, checkbox etc. I don't know if this was fixed in 7.4.